# Raspberry Pi 2 no longer connects to screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hdmi, display, screen

I am the proud owner of a Raspberry Pi 2. I have had it for a while now with no major hiccoughs however today I noticed it no longer connected to my 10yr old TV, via HDMI. I have tested it on another screen with the same cable, and it works.

I have tried various methods such as restarting the Pi, restarting the screen, and removing then re-inserting the HDMI cable.

If anyone could help this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

KittyKatCoder

Comment: Did you change any configuration stuff on your Pi?

Comment: I have not changed anything on it since weeks ago. I last used the Pi a few days ago.

Comment: Is your TV okay?

Comment: Test another device (DVD player, laptop) on that TV using that HDMI cable. Try a different HDMI port on the TV. Ports go bad over time.

Comment: Might be worth a look if you are unaware of it: https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options Although IMO continuing to use it at all with that TV is a bit of gamble, since the ultimate cause, and ultimate consequences, aren't known.

Comment: @tlhIngan I will test another device on the port. In the event it does not work, what can I do?

Comment: @KittyKatCoder If it doesn't work, it looks like a bad HDMI port on the TV. Replacing them involves some surgery, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Further to the 'It's the TV' comments, if you're checking whether the TV's HDMI socket has physical issues it's worth giving the connector a *very mild* wiggle while everything's plugged in. Physical faults are often related to solder joints failing over time, which manifests as intermittent connection failure. If you see things connecting/disconnecting while you're moving the plug about it would strongly suggest a physical failure.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check tomorrow (it's evening where I am)